# How to limit WebRole instance size in Azure?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2015, azure-web-roles, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services

How I might put a check into the build to make sure an invalid VM size is not accidentally uploaded?

**Background:** I recently became aware of just how easy it is to inadvertently configure an Azure WebRole instance VM size to an 'expensive' option on Azure.

*At the risk of appearing very stupid, and for those who are interested, this is how I did it... I was exploring the settings of my WebRole in Visual Studio, and I must have changed the default single 'ExtraSmall' (AO) VM size to multiple 'ExtraLarge' (A4) which when next deployed, resulted in my usage jumping to many dollars a day, and running out of Azure credit quite quickly ... Doh!!*

**It got me thinking about how I might put a check into the build to make sure an invalid VM size is not accidentally uploaded?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After considering various powershell, and azure api approaches, I decided the quickest and easiest way was to add a pre-build event on the Cloud Service project (the one that has the .csdef file) as follows...

```
for /F "tokens=5 delims=<>= " %%n in ('findstr "vmsize=" $(ProjectDir)ServiceDefinition.csdef') do (if "ExtraSmall"==%%n (exit 0) else (exit 1))
```

That's it!

For those who want to know how it works... this pre-build event is a command line/batch file command that can be placed directly in the pre-build events of the project, on a single line.  It opens the `ServiceDefinition.csdef` file and finds the line that contains the text '`vmsize=`'.  This returns the following line...

```
<WebRole name="WCFServiceWebRole1" vmsize="ExtraSmall">
```

Then, using the following characters as delimiters (<,>,=,{space}), it takes the 5th token from that line, which in this case gives us...

```
"ExtraSmall"
```

...It then compares that value against the literal string "ExtraSmall", and returns errorlevel 0 if it matches, or errorlevel 1 if not.  returning errorlevel 1 fails the build and stops any subsequent package and deployment from resulting in the wrong VM size from being deployed in Azure.

Comment: **UPDATE:** on the new Azure Portal, there is a checkbox which says... Allow the update if role sizes change or if the number of roles change.  If this is left un-checked, then this would also stop the VM size from being accidentally changed.  But I do like catching it at the build stage, so I think I'm going to leave the pre-build event in place.